# Exclude specific character from being entered into text field Python guizero

Tags: python, user-input, guizero

I have a gui using python guizero that has multiple textfields for inserting integer values into a database. When the space bar is pressed, some action is performed as can be seen in the following code:

```
app = App(title="App", layout="auto", width=100%, height=100%)

def toggle(event_data):
    if(event_data.key == " "):
        print("space has been toggled")
        #perform some action

app.when_key_pressed = toggle
```

The toggle functionality works as expected, the issue is that when the space bar is pressed a space is added to the textfield which is not desired.

Is there a way to exclude the space bar from the input into the textfield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will remove all whitespace.

```
from guizero import*

app=App() 

input_box = TextBox(app)


def key_pressed(e):
    if e.key == "":#provents an errors
        return None
    elif ord(e.key) == 32:# key number is the ASCII code for the space bar
        #More key numbers
        #https://theasciicode.com.ar/
        print("space has been pressed")
        #Removes white space
        input_box.value=input_box.value.strip()

input_box.when_key_pressed = key_pressed                      
input_box.when_key_released = key_pressed      

app.display()
```